# Spring Boot Rest response returning login.jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

[image][image]

I am learning Spring Boot. I created a sample **Spring Boot Web Application** with **Spring Boot security** and it is working perfectly.
 Now I want to add Rest Webservices functionality in same web application.

**ISSUE:**
When i am trying to access any API, in response I am getting login.jsp .
**Requirement:** I want JSON respnse authentication and authorization not required.
What changes I need to do to achieve this.

**WebSecurityConfig  :**

```
@Configuration  
@EnableWebSecurity <br>
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl") <br>
    @Autowired <br>
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the URL you are calling in your form post

Comment: I am testing using Postman URI:

Comment: what is that uri

Comment: @Dickens I am testing using Postman URI: http://localhost:8080/jobseekers/api/user/admin  "here 'admin' is PathVariable"

Comment: please post the Request Mapping code for `/jobseekers/api/user/admin` I suspect yuo are using Spring MVC with JSP view mapping in web.xml and applicationcontext.xml

Comment: <b>application.properties :</b>

spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jobseekers?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.datasource.username = root 
spring.datasource.password = root 
spring.datasource.platform=mysql 
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /  
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp 
spring.messages.basename=validation 
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath*:/mybatis/*Mapper.xml

Comment: no, /user/admin is mapped in one of your service code, I want that code

Comment: @DickensAS Just now i edited my post with screenshot of UserRestController and ServletInitializer

Comment: add that path to `antMatchers` to permitAll, `antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration", "/api/user/**")` this will disable security for that URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add that path to `antMatchers` to permitAll,

`antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration", "/api/user/**").permitAll()`

this will disable security for that URL